# How to make a perfect dead symbolic link

Tags: linux, unix, symlink

In Linux or Unix systems, it is easy to make dead symbolic links. Just point to a non-existing file:

```
$ ln -sf dummy dead-link
```

The problem with this is that you can easily break it by just doing:

```
$ touch dummy
```

You could just make one by pointing it to itself:

```
$ ln -sf dead-link dead-link
```

This, however, creates often recursive problems and such circular dependencies can create problems in other scripts that attempt to follow links.

```
$ find . -folow -type l
find: ‘./dead-link’: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

**Question:** is it possible to create a dead link that does not resolve in a circular symbolic link-chain, cannot be broken by just touching a file and more importantly:

```
$ [[ ! -e dead-link ]] && [[ -h dead-link ]] && yes
yes
```

or

```
$ readlink -f dead-link
```

fails

Comment: I know this question is not really 100% fitting for this forum. If requested, we can move it to [su] or [unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

1 - Perhaps it's a bit of cheating, but:

```
$ NAME=$(yes | head -n 256 | tr -d '\n')
$ echo ${#NAME} # length of the string "$NAME"
256
$ echo $NAME
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
$ ln -s $NAME dead-link
$ [[ ! -e dead-link ]] && [[ -h dead-link ]] && echo yes
yes
$ readlink -f dead-link; echo $? # 0 if readlink succeeds, 1 if failed
1
$ cat dead-link 
cat: dead-link: File name too long
$ touch $NAME
touch: cannot touch 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy': File name too long
```

So no circular dependency (which I wouldn't worry about anyway), but you'll get "file name too long" errors...

This is leveraging the Linux limitation of 255 characters on file names.

2 - Abusing `/proc`:

```
$ ln -s /proc/dead dead-link
$ [[ ! -e dead-link ]] && [[ -h dead-link ]] && echo yes
yes
$ readlink -f dead-link; echo $? # 0 if readlink succeeds, 1 if failed
/proc/dead
0
$ cat dead-link 
cat: dead-link: No such file or directory
$ touch /proc/dead
touch: cannot touch '/proc/dead': No such file or directory
```

This one assumes (and rightfully so) that procfs is mounted on `/proc` and that the kernel hasn't magically decided to create a file called `dead` within it - nobody else can do it.

Note that unlike `/dev`, nobody can ever write to `/proc` from userspace.

Actually, this one might even be slightly more portable.

Comment: Why would you choose /proc/ over /dev/?

Comment: @kvantour `/dev/` is usually writeable